# How to create an IIS redirect rule to add missing parent directory

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I have a site that recently made a few changes to its structure.
Before the change, accessing the blog had a URL like follows:

example.com/en/Blog

After the change the new URL is the following:

example.com/en/News-and-Video/Blog

I'm trying to add a rule to add the "/News-and-Video/" if it is missing, keeping the language (may be different) and the rest of the path the same. I haven't been able to get a regex expression to accomplish this. Any ideas are greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This rule rill redirect your requests to old blog url `/**/Blog/****` into new URL `/**/News-and-Video/Blog/****` (i presume that your language code has two letters)

```
<rule name="Redirect home to /pages/page1.aspx" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(\w{2})\/Blog/(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}/news-and-video/blog/{R:2}" />
</rule>
```